# Body element pushed down when using bootstrap 5.2 toast element

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-5

When I am using a bootstrap 5 toast it pushes down the whole body, I believe I am doing something wrong with my relative and absolute position attributes but am unsure. My first time using stack overflow so im a little unsure but heres my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
  

    <?php
        require("functions.php");
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            $classinfo = getClassInfo($_GET['id']);
            echo("<title>".$classinfo[0]["course_code"]."</title>");
        }
        else{
            ?>
            <title>ERROR<title>
            <?php
        }

    ?>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">



    <?php
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/login/classes/api.php');

        if (!$user->userAllowedAccess("progress_teacher")) {
            //THEY ARE NOT ALLOWED HERE
              header("location: /login/?p=login&l=/students-assign/19-Aslan/491819/project/teacherLandingPage.php");
            }

        $userEmail = $user->getEmail();
        $userinfo = getCoursesbyEmail($userEmail);
        
       
        

        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            $classinfo = getClassInfo($_GET['id']);
            $commList = getCommentsbyId($userinfo[0]["teacher_id"]);



            
       
    ?>

    <!-- Toast Saved Notification -->
    <div style= "position: relative; margin: 0;">
        <div class="toast-container position-absolute p-3" id="toastPlacement">
            <div class="toast fade" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" id="savedNotification" style="z-index:1;" >
                <div>
                    <div class="toast-header">
                        <strong class="me-auto">System</strong>
                        <small class="text-muted">Just now</small>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toast-body">
                        Data saved.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    

    <div style="position: relative;"> 
    <div class = "userDropdown">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="commentList.php?id=<?php echo($userinfo[0]["teacher_id"])?>" role="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">comment_bank</span></a>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">account_circle</span>
                    <?php echo($userinfo[1]["teacher_name"]); ?>
                </button>   
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="teacherLandingPage.php">Home</a></li></a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/login/?p=login&l=/students-assign/19-Aslan/491819/project/"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">logout</span>Logout</a></li></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    


    <form name='classEval' method="post">
        <div class = "container-md mt-5 mx-auto w-75">
            <table class="table table-hover" >
                <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" onclick="saveEvalData()" class="btn btn-success">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-repeat" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11.534 7h3.932a.25.25 0 0 1 .192.41l-1.966 2.36a.25.25 0 0 1-.384 0l-1.966-2.36a.25.25 0 0 1 .192-.41zm-11 2h3.932a.25.25 0 0 0 .192-.41L2.692 6.23a.25.25 0 0 0-.384 0L.342 8.59A.25.25 0 0 0 .534 9z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3c-1.552 0-2.94.707-3.857 1.818a.5.5 0 1 1-.771-.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 13.917 7H12.9A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8 3zM3.1 9a5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8.757 2.182.5.5 0 1 1 .771.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 2.083 9H3.1z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                
                    <tr class = "text-center align-middle">
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Comment</th>
                        <th scope="col">Level</th>
                        <th scope="col">Request Interview</th>
                    </tr>
                


    
    <?php

        foreach ($classinfo as $student){

            $studentEval = getEvalId($_GET['id'], $student["stud_id"]); //input id and stud id to find user info for filling out the from


            if (count($studentEval)== 0){
                $studentEval["0"]["eval_comments"] = "";
                $studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] = 0;
                $studentEval["0"]["eval_interviewReq"] = 0;


            }


        ?>
    
        <tr>
            <td class = "text-center align-middle">
                <div class = "checkbox-lg">
                    <label class="checkbox-wrap checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <?php
            echo("<td class = 'text-center align-middle'>".$student["stud_name"]."</td>");
            ?>

             

           
             
            <td class = "text-center align-middle">
                <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
                    <?php
                        echo('<input name="inputText_'.$student["stud_id"].'"id="inputText_'.$student["stud_id"].'"value ="'.$studentEval["0"]["eval_comments"].'" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">')
                    ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Comments</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                    <?php
                        foreach($commList as $comm)
                            echo('<li><a onclick=\'addComment("inputText_'.$student["stud_id"].'","'.$comm['comm_value'].'");\' class="dropdown-item" >'.$comm['comm_value'].'</a></li>');


                    ?>
                </div>


            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
                echo('<select class="form-select-sm" aria-label="Default select example" id = "level_'.$student["stud_id"].'" name = "level_'.$student["stud_id"].'">');
            ?>
                    <option <?php if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] == 0) echo ("selected "); ?>value="0">Select</option>
                    <option  <?php if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] == 1) echo ("selected ");?>value="1">Needs Improvement</option>
                    <option  <?php if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] == 2) echo ("selected ");?>value="2">Approaching Expectations</option>
                    <option  <?php if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] == 3) echo ("selected ");?>value="3">Meeting Expectations</option>
                    <option  <?php if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_level"] == 4) echo ("selected ");?>value="4">Exceeding Expectations</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class = 'text-center align-middle'>
                <div class = "checkbox-lg">
                    <label class="checkbox-wrap checkbox-primary ">
                        <?php
                        echo(' <input type="checkbox" id = "intv_'.$student["stud_id"].'" name = "intv_'.$student["stud_id"].'"');

                        if ($studentEval["0"]["eval_interviewReq"] == 1)
                            echo (" checked >"); 
                        else 
                            echo(">");
                        ?>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>



            </tr>
            <?php
        }

        
            
    ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>




        




        <?php
        }else{
            ?>
            <META http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://wcss.emmell.org/login/?p=login&l=/students-assign/19-Aslan/491819/project/teacherLandingPage.php">
            <h2>ERROR: No selected course. Redirecting...</h2>


           <?php 
        }

            
    ?>
        
    <script>
        var option = {
            animation : true,
            delay: 2000
        };


            function saveEvalData(){


                var toastHTMLElement = document.getElementById("savedNotification"); 
                var toastElement = new bootstrap.Toast(toastHTMLElement, option);
                toastElement.show();


                var courseId = <?php echo $_GET["id"]?>

                let form = new FormData(document.forms.classEval);
                let formData = new URLSearchParams(form).toString();

                console.log(formData);

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Making a new request to another page
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //If state is correct and it doesn't error (404)

                    if (this.responseText == 1) { 
                        
                        
                    }
                    }
                    else if (this.readyState == 4) {



                    //error scenario
                    }
                };

                console.log("processData.php?id="+courseId+"&"+formData);

                xhttp.open("GET", "processData.php?id="+courseId+"&"+formData); //Declaring the method and the file name of which we want to go to
                xhttp.send(); //Sending to file            
        }

        function addComment(textBoxId,text) {
            if (document.getElementById(textBoxId).value != "")
                document.getElementById(textBoxId).value += " " + text;
            else
                document.getElementById(textBoxId).value += text;
        }
    </script>
            

        
</body>
</html>
```

I have inspected element and tried to tune the css styling but nothing seems to work. When removing the toast it seems to work fine and be positioned properly but I am unsure. Thanks for all the future help and sorry for the messy code ahaha.

Comment: I tested it on codepen and w3school editor. it's working well without the issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/seniordev009/pen/wvxKvQW?editors=1111    check this url and let me know. I removed the php code part and test it.

Comment: @DavidF thanks for the help! I got it all figured out now :)

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

All fixed! the margin on the div caused it to push the whole body or something??? it was the mt-5 class used here:

```
<form name='classEval' method="post">
        <div class = "container-md mt-5 mx-auto w-75">
            <table class="table table-hover" >
                <tr>
```